# Dropdown freezes when using knockout binding for click

Tags: jquery, performance, knockout.js

I am using knockout binding on my htm view in ASP.NET MVC project. I am binding a click event to a knockout property. Once I select a value in the dropdown the click event gets called, however the event has complex coding and it takes a little while to complete(5 seconds). Till then, the dropdown menu is freezed(in the expanded mode). Once the method is complete, dropdown will shrink.

How can we overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

If it has complex coding it's nothing odd in its behaviour. Try to bind items before user wants to select the dropdown item and/or optimise your code, and the problem should be gone.

Comment: Thats something I am already working on. But would have been better if I could at least show a loading image. Even if I call the UI block before the complex code execution, the load image freezes before it starts. It starts showing once the code is done and hence of no use. :)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found the answer.

I moved the complex piece of code into a setTimeout function.

So,

```
setTimeout(function{
   // Complex function body  
}, 20);
```

Thats it. :)